# How to edit this SQL query so as to display the data in the requested way?

Tags: php, mysql

I save the visits and the time of users in my page. The mySQL is like below:

```
id  - user - page - timestamp
340 - 1 - page1 - 2009-05-18 22:11:11
339 - 1 - page3 - 2009-05-18 22:10:01
337 - 1 - page2 - 2009-05-18 22:06:00
336 - 1 - page1 - 2009-05-18 22:05:10
```

In the above example, user 1, first visits page1, then page2, page3 and again page1.

The sql query I use now is the below:

and the result is:

```
page1 (last page)
page3
page2 (first page)
```

but in fact, the correct output should be

```
page1 (last page)
page3
page2
page1 (first page)
```

The problem is that if the user visits the same page, it does not show all the times visited the specific page, but it moves it on top. So the path is not correct.

What changes shall I make to the SQL query so as to solve this?

Comment: downvoter, please explain the reason

Comment: There's something wrong with your description : the view of your table does not match the way you describe it (the last "page1" is associated with "user2" in the table, but with "user1" in your description).

Comment: @Loufylouf it was a typo. fixed. thanks

Comment: BTW, I'm not the downvoter, but that may be an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you group by page, so the multiple visits are collapsed in one by date.

Drop also the max(timestamp) and the group by date... they makes the double visit disappear

```
SELECT 
page,
`timestamp` 
from behaviour 
WHERE `hash` = 'user1' 
order by `timestamp` desc
```

Comment: to be honest I did this, but the result was not the expected. It stills group them

Answer (score 0):

You should delete the `page` column in your `group by` .

Comment: to be honest I did this, but the result was not the expected. It stills group them

Answer (score 0):

The correct is the result shown (three result).

If i am understood it correctly, you save user id with the data.

From your example, first 3 visit recorded a `user.id = 1`, then last one with `user.id = 2`. Then you cannot get the last one if you trying to queue `user 1` visit record. Therefore, you are getting the "wrong" output (It is correct but i thought it is wrong)

You have to make sure the `user.id` is related to the ***pimery key*** of user table in order to get correct output

**UPDATE 1:**

Ok, I saw the update again. This time then, if you group your results by one ***attribute***, the same value in this ***attribute*** will only display once. You do not need the `group by page` queue.

I think it is better to group by `user` or with `date` (date is not necessary unless you want to)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is when you are grouping the result by page id also. try omitting that and check the result.

Comment: This should be a comment. Not a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't result should be

- page1
- page2
- page3
- page1

according to time

if that is the case this will work

```
  select page, timestamp = min(timestamp) from  behaviour group by page,timestamp
```